# Overload assignment operator for assigning sql::ResultSet to struct tm

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, variable-assignment

Are there exceptions for types which can't have thier assignment operator overloaded?

Specifically, I'm wanting to overload the assignment operator of a [struct tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/tm/) (from time.h) so I can assign a sql::ResultSet to it.

I already have the conversion logic:

```
sscanf(sqlresult->getString("StoredAt").c_str(), "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d",
  &TempTimeStruct->tm_year, &TempTimeStruct->tm_mon, &TempTimeStruct->tm_mday,
  &TempTimeStruct->tm_hour, &TempTimeStruct->tm_min, &TempTimeStruct->tm_sec);
```

I tried the overload with this:

```
tm& tm::operator=(sql::ResultSet & results)
{
  /*CODE*/
  return *this;
}
```

However VS08 reports:

> error C2511: 'tm &tm::operator =(sql::ResultSet &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'tm'

Comment: Can you just inherit from the tm struct and overload the operator there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment operator must be a member function (of `struct tm` in this case), so the only way of doing this would be to modify the standard library itself, something you should definitely not do. You can of course write a named free function to do whatever you want.

Comment: Grand thanks, already done just thought i wuold try and score some extra assignment marks as its the only place im doing any kind of assignment.

Comment: @Luke if this is for school, i strongly discourage you to introduce this "cleverness" into your code. I imagine most teachers will punish you for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct mytm : public tm {
  mytm& operator =(tm const& input) {
     /* whatever you want it to do. */
  return *this;
};
```

Some folks don't think much of this. I'll attach the following caveat:

If you got a ton of `tm` items (or any other classic c-lib struct) floating around in your code, and you want to take control over them, wrapping a class around them this way allows you do so. Just doing it for a 3-line knockoff is probably not a great idea. It's possible that the critics would prefer:

```
struct mytm {
  tm the_tm;
  /* etc */
};
```

Instead.

Comment: Bad for any number of reasons.

Comment: Well, I've made good use of it over the years. Chacun a son goat.

Comment: I can see that this could be useful in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
tm to_tm(sql::ResultSet const& results) {
  tm ret;
  int r = sscanf(results->getString("StoredAt").c_str(), "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d",
    &ret->tm_year, &ret->tm_mon, &ret->tm_mday,
    &ret->tm_hour, &ret->tm_min, &ret->tm_sec);
  if (r != 6) throw std::runtime_error("sscanf: unexpected results");
  return ret;
}

void example() {
  tm t = to_tm(results);
}
```